# Executing Userscripts in Google Chrome permanentely without 3rd party Extension

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension, userscripts

I wrote some userscripts (in JS) and want to execute/run them permanentely **as fast as possible** without using Extensions like Tampermonkey, Greasemonkey or Control Freak.

I found out that 3rd party Extensions like Tampermonkey reduce the userscript performance quite significantly (0,08 Sec runtime instead of 0,02 Sec for example).

I found 2 alternaitves which are both not really convenient for me:

1) I execute my scripts in the Chrome Console whenever I start the browser. Which is kinda annoying if you have do that several times a day.

2) If I add my userscript as Chrome Extension, but then it gets disabled automatically as soon as I restart Chrome as the source is not know in the Chrome Web Store.

Is there any workaround for those 2 problems? What would you suggest?

Comment: Put it in the chrome web store, but don't publish the link?

Comment: If my solution below doesn't work, see [this page](https://github.com/YePpHa/YouTubeCenter/issues/524#issuecomment-46626199) for others.  eg, Chrome Dev-Channel, or whitelisting.

Answer (score 1):

Don't use pack the extension into a `.crx`.  Unpacked extensions work fine.

1. Open the extensions page, and check the "Developer Mode" box at the top right.
2. Click "Load unpacked extensions..." and select your extension's directory.

Comment: 3. OK the d*mn permissions dialog forever after.

Comment: I don't have that problem. Do more people?

Comment: once you load an extension from a local directory, chrome will warn you about it forever after whenever you start chrome. its to avoid viruses installing extensions behind users backs.